# error on load fixture symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

When i run symfony command to load fixtures

i have an error

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'topic_id' cannot be null
```

maybe it's becouse coloumn topic_id from table tags have relation manyToMany with table topic coloumn topic_id

my fixture

```
<?php
class LoadTopicContentData extends AbstractFixture implements OrderedFixtureInterface
{
    public function getOrder()
    {
        return 1; // the order in which fixtures will be loaded
    }

    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $contentTopic1 = new TopicContent();
        $contentTopic1->setTopicId(1);



        $manager->flush();
    }


}
```

my Entity

```
<?php

namespace Application\ClubBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * TopicContent
 */
class TopicContent
{

    /**
     * Set topic_id
     *
     */
    public function setTopicId($topicId)
    {
        $this->topic_id = $topicId;

        return $this;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
{
    $contentTopic1 = new TopicContent();
    $contentTopic1->setTopicId(1);
    $manager->persist($contentTopic1);
    $manager->flush();
}
```

You must persist the object before before call flush (read doctrine documentation for further information).

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution.
must add the merge reference, before load fixture.

```
$contentTopic1->setTopic( $manager->merge($this->getReference('topic1')));
```

and

```
$this->addReference('topic1', $topic1);
```

in main fixture

Comment: You must share object with addReference() from [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html). Data are insert in your database without persist()?